# how to actuate pneumatic muscle by the signals received by emg sensors interfaced with raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, matlab

My aim is to actuate a pneumatic muscle based on signals received by EMG sensors placed on the biceps. Is there any Matlab code which can process the received EMG signals and convert them into any form which can be useful for muscle actuation?

The linked video gives better insight to my question: [exoskeleton arm pneumatic muscle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdoblvmTixA&ab_channel=JamesiosoHo)